# Nr. of combinations given K stars and N borders

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am given K stars(X's) and N inner borders, in how many unique ways can I arrange them ? empty spaces between borders is allowed.

Some examples:

0 inner borders and 3 stars => 1 combination (if no inner borders then we always have only 1 possible combination)

### |XXX|

1 inner border and 3 stars => 4 combinations

### |XX|X|

### |X|XX|

### |XXX| |

### | |XXX|

2 inner borders and 2 stars => 6 combinations

### |XX| | |

### | |XX| |

### | | |XX|

### |X|X| |

### |X| |X|

### | |X|X|

at 3 inner borders and 3 stars I get 20 combinations

I just don't see the pattern here.

Comment: Interesting - this problem with stars and borders typically comes from figuring out the number of ways to choose $n$ total things with $k$ options (eg. a dozen donuts with five flavors)

Comment: If looking for a pattern, do the small cases systematically  and compare with Pascal's triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think finding a pattern here would be pretty hard since there are two variables, so instead, let's think this out using a combinatoric argument.

If we have $N$ borders and $K$ stars, then we have $N+K$ objects. The number of ways we can arrange $N+K$ distinct objects is $(N+K)!$. However, we need to account for the fact that the $N$ borders are all basically the same. Since there are $N!$ ways to arrange the $N$ borders, we divide the number of possible ways by $N!$. Also, since all of the $K$ stars are basically the same, we divide the number of possible ways by $K!$. Thus, we are left with:
$$\frac{(N+K)!}{N!\cdot K!}={N+K \choose K}$$